# Restarting a service with jenkins

Tags: windows-services, jenkins-pipeline

My company is using Jenkins for their CI and so far we've only been using it for our web apps, but now we're getting to the windows service apps we use and I'm looking for some guidance on this.

Currently we have a batch script that shuts down the service then do an Hg update and then turns the service back on.

I need Jenkins to run it as admin so that windows will allow the script to toggle the services.

My question is, how hard is it for Jenkins to run something with elevated privileges?

Comment: Have you tried something? Like to restart the service remotely from windows cmd or powershell by passing username and password? If you can do this? If it can be done from command line, it can be done from jenkins

Comment: I've tried it and it says it doesn't have enough permission so I need it to do a sudo-like thing

Answer (score 0):

With [PsService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/psservice) you can execute a remote command (start/stop/restart) and provide a username and a password for elevated access.

Once you manage to do this all you need to do is to "write that line" in jenkins. Meaning that if you use pipeline you'll do it with [credentials binding](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). Of course you need to create jenkins credentials with the aforementioned username and password.